# Use different formulas to calculate a column in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I want to calculate a column called `result` using different formulas based on the other variable.

Here is an example.

```
library(data.table)
# my formulas
formulas <- c('(a+b)/2', 'a*b', 'a/b', 'b^2+a')

temp <- data.table(a = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                   b = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                   formula = sample(formulas, size = 100, replace = T))
temp[, 'result':=eval(parse(text = formula))]
```

The problem here is that no matter what the `formula` column is, all the values in `results` are calculated using the average, which is the first formula. I know I could always create one column per formula, but I still want to ask if there is a better way?

How can I fix it? Is it the most efficient method?

Here is a snippet of the table:

```
> temp[1:10]
             a           b formula       result
 1: -3.2133845 -0.78415565   b^2+a -1.998770087
 2:  1.0723745 -0.31782577     a/b  0.377274341
 3:  0.2269515 -0.15369020     a*b  0.036630652
 4:  0.3339993 -0.86385430     a*b -0.264927499
 5:  2.1118212  0.33736843     a/b  1.224594821
 6:  0.9475773 -0.95697168 (a+b)/2 -0.004697187
 7:  0.1912716 -1.71286598     a/b -0.760797195
 8:  0.7773886 -0.01156844 (a+b)/2  0.382910072
 9: -1.3132885  0.42693258 (a+b)/2 -0.443177939
10:  0.4569847 -0.70861707   b^2+a -0.125816205
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval(parse` uses only the first expression.  so we need to loop by either using a group by sequence of row

```
temp[,  result := eval(parse(text = formula)), 1:nrow(temp)]
head(temp, 10)
#             a           b formula      result
# 1: -0.8745498  1.59139467   b^2+a   1.6579872
# 2:  1.8701160 -0.04637923     a/b -40.3222721
# 3:  0.7160009  1.20070549     a*b   0.8597063
# 4: -0.3374944  1.18557927     a/b  -0.2846662
# 5:  1.0452618 -0.60531471 (a+b)/2   0.2199735
# 6:  1.1730676 -0.29384938     a/b  -3.9920710
# 7:  1.4913614 -0.44015278     a/b  -3.3882811
# 8:  1.6538467 -0.18478224     a/b  -8.9502472
# 9: -0.1331562  1.84615754   b^2+a   3.2751415
#10:  1.3096422 -0.39569134     a/b  -3.3097570
```

-checking

```
1.8701160/-0.04637923
#[1] -40.32227
0.7160009 * 1.20070549  
#[1] 0.8597062
```

---

Or with `Map`

```
temp[, result := unlist(Map(function(x, a, b) 
           eval(parse(text = x))), formula, a, b)]
```